# Can't connect to IPv6 network

Tags: debian, ipv6

my problem is that my server is not able to reach the ipv6 network.
When i type in `ping6 ipv6.google.com` it returns `connect: Network is unreachable`.

`ifconfig`says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 96:38:ab:cb:38:9f
          inet addr:46.38.255.73  Bcast:46.38.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9438:abff:fecb:389f/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a03:4000:19:30::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3782146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4512051 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5766698254 (5.3 GiB)  TX bytes:1145167693 (1.0 GiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:204810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:204810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:222448000 (212.1 MiB)  TX bytes:222448000 (212.1 MiB)
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` contains:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 static
       address 2a03:4000:19:30::1
       netmask 64
       gateway fe80::1
```

`ip -6 route` contains:

```
root@flosserver:/# ip -6 route
2a03:4000:19:30::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
root@flosserver:/#
```

Comment: I don't see the default route in there. But it's configured in your interfaces file. Try restarting networking or restarting the computer.

Comment: I rebooted and could connect but after a few hours the problem came back

Comment: Are you sure about your default route? address `fe80::1` look suspicious. Can you send `ip -6 route` output after reboot, when `ping6` wokrs?

Comment: I think my os is corrupted because i migrated from openvz to kvm. Thanks for your help but i will reinstall the entire server.

Comment: @Quantim It depends on how the router was configured. I have this routing table entry on a server which is working just fine: `default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 1024  advmss 1220`